# My image validator somehow affects my HttpPostedFileBase value

Tags: c#, image, fluentvalidation

So I need to validate the image uploads in my application. I'm using some code that I probably got from here and something very weird happens. Firstly, the way my validation works is I use fluent custom validation classes. For the image validation, I just validate the `HttpPostedFileBase` field and then I use a little helper function for turning it into a byte array before saving it into my database. Now for the weird part..

When I don't apply my validator on the field, the image upload, conversion to byte array, and save to db works fine. But when I use my validator I end up with an empty byte array in the end. So I'm wondering how it's possible for my validation class to affect what's posted in the field.

Here's my image validator class:

```
public class ImageValidator : PropertyValidator
{
    public ImageValidator()
        : base("The allowed formats for the Image are JPEG, PNG and GIF and the maximum allowed size is 1MB.")
    {
    }

    protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
    {
        dynamic viewModel = context.Instance;

        var isValid = false;
        HttpPostedFileBase image = viewModel.UploadedImage;

        if (image == null)
            return true;

        if (image.ContentLength > 1 * 1024 * 1024)
            return false;

        if (IsFileTypeValid(image))
        {
            isValid = true;
        }

        return isValid;
    }

    private bool IsFileTypeValid(HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var img = Image.FromStream(image.InputStream))
            {
                if (IsOneOfValidFormats(img.RawFormat))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool IsOneOfValidFormats(ImageFormat rawFormat)
    {
        var formats = getValidFormats();

        return formats.Contains(rawFormat);
    }

    private IEnumerable<ImageFormat> getValidFormats()
    {
        var formats = new List<ImageFormat> { ImageFormat.Png, ImageFormat.Jpeg, ImageFormat.Gif };

        return formats;
    }
}
```

Here's my function for conversion to byte array (just so I don't get ask about this later):

```
public static byte[] UploadedImageToByteArray(HttpPostedFileBase uploadedImage)
{
    var target = new MemoryStream();
    uploadedImage.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
    return target.ToArray();
}
```

Considering that the validation class is what seems to be the issue I wouldn't put too much attention on the `UploadedImageToByteArray` function.

EDIT:

Okay even weirder things are happening. Regardless of whether I use the image validator class or not, the `uploadedImage` parameter of the `UploadedImageToByteArray` function seems to contain the same value, yet it returns a different result in both scenarios - a valid byte array of the image when I don't use the image validator and an empty byte array when I use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewind the InputStream:

```
    private bool IsFileTypeValid(HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var img = Image.FromStream(image.InputStream))
            {
                return IsOneOfValidFormats(img.RawFormat);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            image.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then NotImplementedException occurs. But the HttpPostFile class's stream suports seeking otherwise you would need to copy the InputStream into a MemoryStream and you would have to validate against the MemmoryStream not the posted file.

Comment: My answer wasn't right, since `CopyTo` reads the entire stream you still need to seek the stream back to the starting point.

Comment: This worked. And I just realized I have a lot more to learn about memory and I/O.